# SFML 2.5.1/VS 2015/C++/Движение персонажа

Tags: c++, sfml

Изучаю С++. Пробую написать простую игру с использованием SFML.
Создал базовый класс `Entity.h`:

```
#ifndef _ENTITY_
#define _ENTITY_

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

class Entity
{
public:

    float       e_X, e_Y, e_dX, e_dY, e_Speed;
    int         e_Height, e_Width, e_Health;
    bool        e_Life, e_onGround;

    Texture     e_Texture;
    Sprite      e_Sprite;
    String      e_Name;

    Entity(Image &Image, float X, float Y, int Height, int Width, String Name);
};

#endif
```

Его реализация `Entity.cpp`:

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(Image &Image, float X, float Y, int Height, int Width, String Name) :
    e_X(X), e_Y(Y), e_Height(Height), e_Width(Width), e_Name(Name)
{
    e_dX = 0, e_dY = 0, e_Speed = 0, e_Health = 100;
    e_Life = true, e_onGround = true;

    e_Texture.loadFromImage(Image);
    e_Sprite.setTexture(e_Texture);
}
```

Далее есть класс `Player.h`:

```
#ifndef _PLAYER_
#define _PLAYER_

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Entity.h"

using namespace sf;

enum class FRKey
{
    STAY,
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    DOWN,
    UP
};

class Player:public Entity
{
public:

    FRKey pl_Key;

    int         pl_Lives, pl_Score;

    Player(Image &Image, float X, float Y, int Height, int Width, String Name);

    void setControls();

    void Update(float Time);
};

#endif
```

Его реализация `Player.cpp`:

```
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(Image &Image, float X, float Y, int Height, int Width, String Name) :
    Entity(Image, X, Y, Height, Width, Name)
{
    pl_Key = FRKey::STAY, pl_Lives = 5, pl_Score = 0;
    
    e_Sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(48, 32, 16, 16));
    e_Sprite.setPosition(e_X, e_Y);
}
 
void Player::setControls()
{
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed)
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
        {
            pl_Key = FRKey::RIGHT;

            e_Speed = 0.1; 
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
        {
            pl_Key = FRKey::LEFT;

            e_Speed = 0.1;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down))
        {
            pl_Key = FRKey::DOWN;

            e_Speed = 0.1;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up))
        {
            pl_Key = FRKey::UP;

            e_Speed = 0.1;
        }
    }
}

void Player::Update(float Time)
{
    setControls();

    switch (pl_Key)
    {
    case FRKey::RIGHT:
        e_dX = e_Speed;
        e_dY = 0;
        break;

    case FRKey::LEFT:
        e_dX = -e_Speed;
        e_dY = 0;
        break;

    case FRKey::DOWN:
        e_dX = 0;
        e_dY = e_Speed;
        break;

    case FRKey::UP:
        e_dX = 0;
        e_dY = -e_Speed;
        break;

    default:
        pl_Key = FRKey::STAY;
        e_dX = 0;
        e_dY = 0;
        break;
    }

    e_X += e_dX*Time;
    e_Y += e_dY*Time;

    e_Speed = 0;

    e_dY += 0.0015*Time;
}
```

Реализация `Main.cpp`:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Player.h"

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow m_Window(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "SFML works!");

    Image m_Character;
    m_Character.loadFromFile("Characters.png");

    Player player(m_Character, 32, 32, 16, 16, "Player");

    Clock m_Clock;


    while (m_Window.isOpen())
    {
        float m_Time = m_Clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();

        m_Clock.restart();
        m_Time /= 1000;

        player.Update(m_Time);

        Event event;

        while (m_Window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                m_Window.close();
        }

        m_Window.clear();
        m_Window.draw(player.e_Sprite);
        m_Window.display();
    }
}
```

Собственно, проблема: персонаж не двигается.
Корректна ли реализация движения через ***enum class FRKey***?
Может какие-то другие не очевидные (для меня) ошибки есть?
Visual Studio ошибок не выдает, все компилируется...

Comment: а вам не кажется эта строка `if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed)` странной?

Comment: Так, нет вроде...
Логика такая: если клавиша нажата, а конкретно - такая-то клавиша,
то выполнить действие.

Comment: isKeyPressed - это функция. Но Вы ее не вызываете, Вы проверяете указатель

Comment: Не понял про указатель... Как я понимаю, функция `isKeyPressed` возвращает значение только true или false

Comment: если Вы делаете вот так `if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))` - то да, Вы вызываете функцию и проверяете состояние кнопки. А вот когда `if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed)`, то функция не вызывается. я бы поставил в функции setControls отладочный вывод в конце и посмотрел бы, меняется ли что то.

Comment: Спасибо! Убрал строку `if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed)`, проверил отладчиком, результат следующий: при нажатии клавиш все распознается, считается. В `main` файле напротив переменной  `m_Window` получаю <Information not available, no symbols loaded for sfml-graphics-d-2.dll>